# How to control the position of label in a tree tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-trees

Here is my graph with a part of code:

```
\tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=2em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{end} = []
\begin{tikzpicture}[sloped]
\node (a) at ( 0,0) [bag] {$\ln r_0$};
\node (b1) at ( 3,1.5) [bag] {$\ln r_{10} + \sigma_1\sqrt{\Delta t_1}$};
```

[image]

But I want label setting above the node like

[image]

Furthermore, how to control the size of  words and don't change the line?

Comment: Isn't this basically a repeat of your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399885/the-words-in-the-node-of-tree)? If so, would have been better to edit that one I think, that bumps it to the top of the front page.

Comment: Regarding line breaking: `text width` sets the node in `minipage`-like box of the specified width, and enables automatic line breaking. You could increase the `text width`, but for your use it would probably be better to use `\tikzset{bag/.style={align=center}}`, in which case the width of the node isn't specified, but manual linebreaking with ```\\``` still works.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes, since I haven't get the answer of previous question, then I simplied the problem and asked again.